# Video file of mpeg format playing only sound in Exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-ffmpeg

I am converting video to mpeg format with mp3 audio codec. After that when, I am playing video using Exoplayer then only audio is playing also video playback time is showing that it's increased. Same video is playing correctly in MX player.

What is the fix for this issue. Can anyone suggest.

Thank you.